# I can't run C files with .h files included in eclipse IDE and Code:Blocks

Tags: c, eclipse

When i include .h files the compiler says no such file or directory
i have installed MinGW in the default path C:\MinGW\
and i have added the MinGW path to environment variables path as C:\MinGW\bin

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <main.h>

int main()
{
#if (DEBUG_MODE)
    printf("Debug Mode!\n");
#else
    printf("No Debug Mode!\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my main.h file

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

#define DEBUG_MODE 1

#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

and this is the error

```
11:02:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.c" 
..\main.c:10:18: fatal error: main.h: No such file or directory
#include <main.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.

11:02:58 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 212ms)
```

Comment: I tried `gcc prac.c -I .` and it was OK.

Comment: Sorry! .. i am not understand you.

Comment: I created a file named `prac.c` containing the `main` function and a file named `main.h` containing the headers in the same directory. then ran `gcc prac.c -I .`. But it is better to use `"main.h"` instead of `<main.h>`.